# Cannot access public static method

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have this class

```
#pragma once
namespace CMT{
namespace sql=System::Data::SqlClient;
public ref class db
{
public:db(void){}
public: static sql::SqlConnection SC(){
            System::String cstring="data source=192.168.0.139\\cedfit; "+
                "initial catalog=cedfitdb; user id=client; password=cedfit";
            sql::SqlConnection sc=new sql::SqlConnection(cstring);
            return sc;
        }

};
}
```

Now when I go to my form 1 load event I cannot access my db's SC() method why?

I also tried to make in the form1 load event this code:

```
System::Data::SqlConnection mycon=db::SC();
mycon.Open();//I also tried mycon->Open() and mycon::Open()
```

Why it doesnt work? Why can't the program recognize the "Open()"?
Also when I put `#include "db.h"` on the CMT.cpp it says that `cannot covert from System::Data::Sqlclient::SqlConnection to int`
I am sure I am returning an SqlConnection but why?

Comment: Could you please indent the code properly and update the question?

Comment: is it okay if i upload the entire solution?

Comment: @user1625766 not necessary. But you should clarify what dialect of C++ you use. It looks like C++/CLI but could be c++/CX as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many errors when trying to use reference types in the .NET framework via C++/CLI.

-- You need to use the ^ when referring to .NET reference types in C++/CLI. Also, when allocating memory for reference types, you need to use `gcnew` instead of `new`. See the changes below:

```
static sql::SqlConnection^ SC()
{
    System::String^ cstring = "data source=" + "asdfasdf";
    sql::SqlConnection^ sc = gcnew sql::SqlConnection(cstring);

    return sc;
}
```

-- This is a problem again when trying to use the method in your code. Additionally, you didn't specify the correct namespace for the `SqlConnection` as well as `CMT::db::SC`.

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    System::Data::SqlClient::SqlConnection^ mycon = CMT::db::SC();
    mycon->Open();

    return 0;
}
```

*As a side note, is there a particular reason you need C++/CLI instead of C#? There are certainly cases where C++/CLI is beneficial, but it can also be unnecessarily complicated if you are not attempting to interop with native code. Just a thought.*

**Full Code:**

***db.h***

```
#pragma once

namespace CMT {
namespace sql = System::Data::SqlClient;

ref class db
{
public:

    db(void)
    {
    }

    static sql::SqlConnection^ SC()
    {
        System::String^ cstring = "whatever";
        sql::SqlConnection^ sc = gcnew sql::SqlConnection(cstring);

        return sc;
    }

};

}
```

***Main.cpp***

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "db.h"

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    System::Data::SqlClient::SqlConnection^ mycon = CMT::db::SC();
    mycon->Open();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1>c:\users\sherwin\desktop\cmt\cmt\Form1.h(73) : error C2039: 'SC' : is not a member of 'CMT'
1>c:\users\sherwin\desktop\cmt\cmt\Form1.h(73) : error C3861: 'SC': identifier not found
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\SHERWIN\Desktop\CMT\CMT\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>CMT - 3 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: @user1625766 well did you include the corresponding *.h file?

Comment: yup I did put #include "db.h" in the CMT.cpp

Comment: @user1625766 and did you put it in the `Form1.h` or where ever you use it? Not to mention like @Inisheer edited it declare it in the right namespace in the `db.h`?

Comment: Working :)
Thank you very much.(I'm originally from c# thats why I cant use c++ properly)
One more question is there any way where I can put all the #include "db.h" headers to a single file instead of putting in at every windows  form? Because I have like 7 forms here

Comment: @user1625766 precompiled headers. But you shouldn't have to include it into most other `.h` files if you only use a reference to the type you  should get away with forward declaring it and include the `.h` only in the implementation (presumably `Form1.cpp`). Again, to echo @Inisheers sentiment, is there a good reason that you use C++/CLI?

Comment: @user1625766 As PeterT said, you should be able to put #include "db.h" in the stdafx.h file and it will be auto included in your forms.